# Using CONCATENATE in a MATCH Function

Tags: arrays, excel, concatenation, match, lookup

So I'm creating a Hyperlink that will go to a specific Tab.  There are multiple tabs.

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#","'",G3,"'","!E")&MATCH(E3,CONCATENATE("'",G3,"'","!E:E"), FALSE),"GO")
```

The first `CONCATENATE` works, but the 2nd one in the `MATCH` function returns `"'G3'!E:E"` and results in a #VALUE! error.

The reason I need it to go to G3 is that's the Tab Name I want it to go to.  Different lines will go to different tabs and I'm trying to make it automatically populate with the Tab Name.

Help! And Thanks in Advance!
~Michelle

Comment: Think you need INDIRECT (though not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Though HyperLink accepts a string, MATCH does not.  So you need to use INDIRECT in the MATCH to turn the string into a viable range reference:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#","'",G3,"'","!E")&MATCH(E3,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",G3,"'","!E:E")), 0),"GO")
```

Comment: Figured that out literally right after I posted!  But thank you so much!!